Identify Shower Valve/Use Delta Handle on a Moen Valve?
Is it possible, i.e. can anyone out there, identify the valve in this pic?  It is a new home build and builder will almost certainly have used least-expensive/builder-grade choice.  Additionally, assuming it is a basic/standard Moen valve, can I expect to put a basic/low-cost Delta handle (trim kit) on it?  I've read one or two threads here that indicate maybe not, or that it depends.


The picture is pretty far away, but that looks a little more like a Delta control. (A closer pic would help.)
Moen and Delta parts are not interchangeable, even the trim. There are aftermarket trim kits for both Delta and Moen products, and others.  However the builder should install a trim kit when it is needed.
(As opinion, Moen products have proven to me to be very reliable and easy to repair when needed. Delta, not so much.)

Sorry about the satellite imagery, this was a snapshot from a video that was shot to generally document the state of build.  And Wow...that's damn impressive...it >>is<< a Delta valve.  Also, it's good to know for future reference that these things are not interchangeable...I wish they were, i.e. a set of industry standards that made it easier on everyone, but understand why manufacturers want to protect their turf.  I'll see about swapping out for a Moen...that would have been my preference as well if I had been asked.
